# Reading a file and changing its content

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that reads content from a text.txt and writes its updated version to the same file.
The text.txt tooks like this:

```
Amata Hock,1.80,88
Mack Romer,1.79,85
```

where the first number is height and the second is weight. For the update of my file I need to calculate the height and the number, so that in the new version there could be displayed only the calculated number.

```
with open("text.txt",'r') as my_file:
    file_str = my_file.read().split("\n")
for i in range(len(file_str)):
    file_str[i] = file_str[i].split(",")
    file_str[i][1] = float(file_str[i][1])
    file_str[i][2] = float(file_str[i][2])
    file_str[i].append( (file_str[i][2]) / (file_str[i][1]**2) )

with open("text.txt", 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write("".join(str(file_str)))
    my_file.close()
```

However, I have encountered a problem with this because in the updated file I still see the height and weight (because I turn them to integers). The updated version looks like this:

```
[['Amata Hock', 1.8, 88.0, 27.160493827160494], ['Mack Romer', 1.79, 85.0, 26.528510346119035]]
```

Is there a way to exclude the weight and height from the updated file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fileinput.input` with `inplace=True` to modify the original file:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("input.txt",inplace=True):
    # split into name weight and height
    name,a,b = line.split(",")
    # write just the name and weight / height ** 2
    print("{},{}".format(name, float(b) / float(a)**2))
```

Output:

```
Amata Hock,27.160493827160494
Mack Romer,26.52851034611903561
```

To do it reopening the file you can store the calculations first the reopen and use csv.writerows to write the data:

```
import csv
with open("input.txt",'r') as f:
    data = ((name, float(b)/float(a)**2) for name, a, b in [line.split(",") for line in f])
    with open("input.txt","w") as out:
        wr = csv.writer(out)
        wr.writerows(data)
```